# Having a function output two quantities in looping structure in R?

Tags: r, function, for-loop, sapply, replicate

In my R function below, I'm wondering how I can change my code such that I can get `pe` out of my `fun` function? Right now, `fun` only outputs `L` and `U`.

**P.S.** Of course, I want to keep the function work as it does right now, so therefore `replicate` may also need to change as a result of having `fun` output `pe` in addition to `L` and `U`.

```
CI.bi = function(n, p, n.sim){

fun <- function(n1 = n, p1 = p){
x <- rbinom(1, size = n1, prob = p1)
pe <- x/n1
res <- binom.test(x, n1, p1)[[4]]
c(L = res[1], U = res[2])
 }

sim <- t(replicate(n.sim, fun()))

y = unlist(lapply(1:n.sim, function(x) c(x, x)))

plot(sim, y, ty = "n", ylab = NA, yaxt = "n")

segments(sim[ ,1], 1:n.sim, sim[ ,2], 1:n.sim, lend = 1)

 }
 # Example of use:
CI.bi(n = 15, p = .5, n.sim = 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have `fun()` return `pe` as an additional element of the return vector.

When referencing `sim` later on, just specify which columns you want to use.  I believe the below code sample replicates your current functionality but has `pe` as an additional output of `fun()`

```
CI.bi = function(n, p, n.sim){

  fun <- function(n1 = n, p1 = p){
    x <- rbinom(1, size = n1, prob = p1)
    pe <- x/n1
    res <- binom.test(x, n1, p1)[[4]]
    c(L = res[1], U = res[2], pe=pe)
  }

  sim <- t(replicate(n.sim, fun()))

  y = unlist(lapply(1:n.sim, function(x) c(x, x)))

  plot(sim[,1:2], y, ty = "n", ylab = NA, yaxt = "n")

  segments(sim[ ,1], 1:n.sim, sim[ ,2], 1:n.sim, lend = 1)

}

CI.bi(n = 15, p = .5, n.sim = 3)
```